# More Continuity True and False

Tags: real-analysis

I seek to show whether the following are true or false:

1. $f$ cts on $[a,b]$ and $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ implies that $f(x)$ is either always positive or negative on [a,b].
2. $f$ cts on $[a,b]$ and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ implies that there exists an $m>0$ such that $f(x) \geq m$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Proposition 1 seems to obviously be true. If $f(x)$ is not equal to $0$, it has to be positive or negative? Am I missing something there?

Prop 2 seems to be false because what if the function approaches $0$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS:

1. Intermediate value theorem.
2. Extreme value theorem. (Note that $x$ can’t approach $\infty$: $x\in[a,b]$.)

Comment: 1. But doesnt $f(x) \neq 0$ void the IVT in a sense?

2. and sorry i made an error in the question! fixed now!

Comment: @PaulGerard: That is exactly right. If the function is positive and negative at separate points, then the IVT implies it has to be zero somewhere, which we know can't be the case.

Comment: @Paul: No. The IVT simply shows that if $f(x)$ is never $0$ on $[a,b]$, it cannot have both positive and negative values on that interval.

Comment: So then logically it has to be true? If it cant be zero, it must be positive or negative?

Comment: @Paul: The IVT says that if $f$ is continuous and takes both a positive and a negative value; it must be $0$ somewhere between those two points. If you know that it’s continuous and never $0$, then you know that it cannot take **both** positive and negative values. Therefore ... ?

Comment: well no, because it does not have to be ALWAYS positive or negative? I think my logic is going in circles...

Comment: @Paul: I don’t understand your last comment, I’m afraid. Suppose that $f(a)>0$; can there be any point $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)<0$?

Comment: Nevermind that, my apologies, I wrote that before your last comment. I think I understand now. Because $f$ is cts on $[a,b]$ and $f(x) \neq 0$, at no point can it cross the x-axis (we know this by the IVT), so all values must either be always positive or negative? Thus, it is true?

Comment: @Paul: Now you’ve got it.

Comment: great thank you, and for the the second one: this also appears to be true (by the EVT)

Comment: @Paul: That’s right: $f$ attains its minimum at some $c\in[a,b]$, and $m=f(c)>0$. You’re welcome.